# error on user register php

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm making a easy user register this give me some errors, i was like 1 hour seeing other questions and answers but nothing can solve my problem, so here is

**FIRST OF ALL MY register.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

 $checkusername = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");

 if(mysqli_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
 {
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
 }
 else
 {
    $registerquery = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
    if($registerquery)
    {
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";   
    }      
 }
}
else
{
?>
 <h1>Register</h1>
 <p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
<fieldset>
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

**NOW MY conexion.php**

```
<?php
//Conexión a la base de datos
$servidor = "localhost"; //Nombre del servidor
$usuario = "myuser"; //Nombre de usuario en tu servidor
$password = "mypass"; //Contraseña del usuario
$base = "db_maquinas"; //Nombre de la BD
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$password","$base") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

this are the errors that given me

**Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 14**

**Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 15**

**Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 16**

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 18**

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 20**

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\register.php on line 27**

i know is about the mysqli, but i tried to figure it but nothing happen the same errors.. before was given me more errors... and i solve some's but still those errors... THX

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp read about params

Comment: You forgot your connect variable for those functions. Check the manual. It explains it.

Comment: @Phantom: don't link to w3fools. They're a useless resource, full of bad code and outright mistakes. being first in google results does NOT mean they're good/useful.

Comment: @Phantom Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the manual instead. It is the best resource.

Comment: You are using mysqli wrong in so many ways, and are theoretically STILL open to sql injection attacks. while `md5()` would never return anything that could be injectable, you should **NEVER** manipulate a string between the time you escape() it and when you insert it into the sql.

Comment: In addition to Marc's comment above, md5 has been vulnerable for a long time and should not be used for passwords.

Comment: so what recommend for encrypt password?, i see the troubles and all give me the answer that i want, really thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simple use `$link` as parameter of those functions:

```
mysqli_query($link, "your query here");
```

and

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link , 'value to escape' );
```

Comment: good! thx to you answer i see the obviusly error >.< really thx my friend!